# Usage of colloquial word (Ach ja)

Tags: colloquial

I am supposed to write a letter to a friend and there is a theme for the letter. In the second paragraph of the letter, I have written the following sentence. Please correct it if the usage is not appropriate (or) if people don't write like this, normally.

The context: For students younger than 25 years, the cost of some 'XYZ' course is just 36€.

> Ach ja, seit sind Sie Vierundzwanzig Jahre alt, er kostet nur 36€

But I initially wrote it like this

> Der preis für den Kurs ist nur 36€, weil Sie Vierundzwanzig Jahre alt sind

Which one is preferable to be written and which one sounds nicer to a German person?

Comment: Questions on homework will likely be closed. To get it reopened it may need an edit to make it a more general question on the meaning or usage of the interjection *"Ach ja"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to indicate with "Ach ja" in the fist sentence. Ach ja works as a phrase realizing a fact in the sense of "Oh right!" which can have a connotation of regret and/or remembering something. Without the context it is hard to say if the usage is correct or not.

But to your first phrase: "Seit" is "since" in a temporal meaning. If you want to have "since" as a causal meaning, you need to use "da" or "weil". Then, there are 2 errors in word order. The correct phrase would be rather

> Ach ja, da Sie vierundzwanzig Jahre alt sind, kostet er nur 36€.

Or

> Ach ja, Sie sind vierundzwanzig Jahre , da kostet er nur 36€.

Which is rather "Right, you are 24, then it only costs..."

Or

> Ach ja, er kostet nur 36€, da Sie vierundzwanzig Jahre alt sind.

Here I used the "er kostet nur" order, which requires it to be the main clause.

The second phrase is correct except you need a capital P for prize and 24 does not have capitals.

As to the difference between  the sentences: The first one, as mentioned, with "Ach ja" indicates that the speaker just realized the described fact, the speaker might have been challenged on the prize by the customer and corrected himself.
The second sentence would be used when the speaker rather explains the prices to someone who inquires, and has the prize right away correctly.

Comment: In my case, the second one applies.. Thanks :-)

Comment: Phrases like the first one are sometimes used in advertisements to get the attention of the reader.